# How to suspend a mongodb stitch trigger within a stitch function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I have a mongodb stitch database trigger that executes a stitch function on collection update. The stitch function in question will connect to amazon kinesis and transmit the database changes. I want to suspend the stitch trigger from with in the function, if there is an error from amazon kinesis. Is there a way to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no administration API for triggers from a Function.

One possible workaround would be to store some enabled/disabled state somewhere and read it from your triggered Function. You can then decide whether to continue based on this state.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your answer. In that case, If i were to use your suggestion, Lets say if a problem occurs in Kinesis, is there a way to manually suspend a database trigger, So that after the problem is sorted out we could resume the trigger using the resume token

Comment: Ah, that is an issue with the suggested workaround. You would lose any events while the state is "disabled".

Comment: Thanks for the response. So to just to make sure, there is no way to manually suspend a trigger?

Comment: Correct, there is currently no way to manually suspend a trigger using code. You can suspend a trigger from the admin console UI of course, but that won't help you for your case. I would suggest bringing it up as a suggested feature on canny: https://mongodb.canny.io/mongodb-stitch

Comment: Chris, Thanks for the response. I will bring it up as a suggested feature request. Just one more question though, if you don't mind, you mention you could suspend a trigger from the admin UI. But i could not find this option, there was only enable/disable. So could you kindly tell me where this option is located. (I am currently using the free tire). Thaks